# UK visit visa refusal with 10 year ban: effect on Canadian visa application

Tags: uk, canada, visa-refusals, visa-bans, serial-refusals

I'm an Indian national who applied for a UK visit visa and got refused with 10 years travel ban to the UK, starting from 2015-2025.

This ban was due to a forged documents issue. The company that I worked for hadn't informed the UKBA about my salary details correctly. After that, I resigned started a new limited liability company with my partner back in 2008.

Now, I'm planing to apply for a Canada general visitor visa. My girlfriend lives in Toronto, Canada, and I want to see her. Will my previous travel ban affect my application for a Canadian visit visa?

Comment: why did you get the 10-year travel ban, and have the surrounding circumstances changed in the intervening time?

Comment: @mlc A 10 year ban from the UK would almost certainly be for deception.

Comment: If you were you I would try to solve the problem with UKVI first. in Canada visa forms you should declare your refusals but there is a section that gives you an opportunity to justify why you have been refused a visa. Try your best there without solving UKVA problem, there is a slim chance they issue a visa for you.

Comment: @Iman Based on the information in the question it’s probably pretty unlikely the OP can ‘solve the problem with UKVI’.

Comment: @Traveller At least he can take a legal actiom particularly if he think he is innocent which he said he is.May be he should pursue it in India first and after getting an in favor verdict, apply for UK to lift their ban. We all know that even after 10 years he would not have a chance for visa in any of the so called 5 eyes. So the only viable action here is to start a case in his own country first and then the other steps.

Comment: The appeals process is described on the UKVI pages of GOV.UK - none of them involve a "get an order from a foreign court saying we shouldn't ban you" step. It's a joke to sovereignty and to the trustworthiness of the Indian judicial system. @Iman

Comment: @Nij you are right. They wouldn’t solely relay on a foreign verdict, yet that would let him to have something  in hand appealing the ban order. Yes it is a long shot, but there is no other option

Comment: It gives then nothing. The UK does not care what another country thinks of its entry ban on a person. It has its own judicial system and appeals process. Instead of wasting money on an Indian lawyer, they could waste it on a UK lawyer (and have no chance even then) or on a Canadian lawyer (makes the application clear enough to at least fail on its own merits). @Iman

Answer (score 8):

Britain and Canada share immigration data under the Five Eyes treaty. You should assume that the Canadians are aware of your ban. Do not be tempted to try to cover up the ban. If the Canadians know and you don't tell them you're likely to get another ban.

Since the Canadians are likely already aware of your ban and the circumstances it is likely that it will make your application more difficult. Exactly what effect it will have will depend on the exact circumstances around the ban, and how well you present yourself in your application.

You might consider using a lawyer with experience in Canadian Immigration matters to help you, but this will be expensive.

Comment: oh really, thank you for the answer, by the way do u can recommended good immigration lawyer with this regards, thanks

Comment: @kumarrathnam Sorry - I can't recommend anyone. Your girlfriend lives in Toronto. She could make a few calls. You could start with the [Canadian Bar Association Find-a-lawyer page](https://www.cba.org/For-The-Public/Find-A-Lawyer)

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my experience. Truly, Canada, UK, USA, Australia and New Zealand share immigration information among themselves, but not in all visa applications.

I applied for a UK student visa via an agent in 2013. The agent used a forged account, and the application was refused with a 10 years ban. The agent went ahead to falsify the letter by removing the part that specified that a fake account was used. He then gave me the falsified letter. I only thought I was refused a visa, I never knew I was banned.

In 2016, I applied for a New Zealand tourist visa. In the form, I stated I was refused UK visa in 2013. New Zealand issued me a tourist visa. In 2019 I applied for a Schengen visa and it was issued.

In 2021 I applied to visit the UK, the application was refused, they stated that I used a fake account in 2013,and I was banned for 10 years and the ban will expire in 2023. That was how I got to know that I was banned.  If I had known about the ban, I would not have applied at all.

My point is, these embassies don't have luxury of time to be wasting on mere tourist and students visas, and they operate different immigration rules. They use the same database which will show to them if the applicant has committed a crime in any of the 5 eyes countries. They are majorly concerned about whether you have a criminal records with any of them, and once you are honest about the past refusals, you are good to go.

Immigration files of individual applications are highly voluminous, and all immigration officers are very limited to time, hence, they can't be going through your UK files while processing your Canada study visa. So my advice is: just state your past refusal, that's all, as long as you have never committed a crime, then, you are good to go.

Comment: Other advice: **never** use an agent. It’s totally unnecessary, self-application online can be done very easily. If you do use an agent, make very sure you supervise what they do and that you know exactly what they submit on your behalf.